# How to fix UIWebView deprecated Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, uiwebview, applet, ionic4

When submitting my latest build, Apple suddenly returned a message saying that there was an issue, specifically:

ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more information.
What that means and are that related to using the IONIC framework.
How to fix it.

Answer (score 15):

The cordova team yesterday released 2019-11-25 a release cordova-ios@5.1.0

This release resolves the ITMS-90809 alert from the apple store.

```
cordova platform remove ios
cordova platform add ios@5.1.0

Add <preference name = "WKWebViewOnly" value = "true" /> to your config.xml file

Run "cordova prepare ios" to apply the changes.
```

https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2019/11/25/cordova-ios-release-5.1.0.html#comment-4702612854

Answer (score 3):

Use cordova-ios version 5.1.0 or above. if you are using facebook4, googleplus, fcm and inappbrowser plugins then upgrade them to latest versions. It is not mandatory to migrate to Capacitor.

add this to your config.xml file

```
<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 2):

First remove cordova ios

```
cordova platform remove ios
```

Add cordova for ios

```
cordova platform add ios@5.1.0
```

Ensure you have a WKWebView plugin installed: if not add by using following command.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@latest
```

Add following to the config.xml file.

```
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
<param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
```

Run cordova prepare ios to apply the changes.

```
cordova prepare ios
```

Comment: I also updated ALL cordova plugins and it worked !!!

Comment: Hi may I know where to do the last step "set webkitframework to required in Xcode"?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently a problem with the Ionic framework, you can follow the [ongoing discussion at the official forums](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/app-store-connect-warning-uiwebview-api-deprecation/172063/32).

Ionic team claims that this warning can be ignored but there are concerns that Apple might indeed reject Apps built with Ionic although no case is known (yet). The suggested solution is [using Capacitor instead of Cordova](https://ionicframework.com/blog/understanding-itms-90809-uiwebview-api-deprecation/) but depending on your usage of Cordova plugins this may not be an option.

Answer (score 0):

Just try use ionic capacitor [Capacitor](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/getting-started/with-ionic/)

or 
update UIWebView to WKWebView

```
rm platform ios & android
```

update and install WKwebView
    ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview --save
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/wkwebview/

Comment: The OP is using Ionic 4 which has always used WKWebView. Also using Capacitor may not be an option if his plugins are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Just try use ionic capacitor Capacitor

https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/

we finally shiftted cordova to capacitor and make it my app

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible right now using cordova, even though using wkwebview there are some references in the code to the uiwebview, so you will have to wait cordova take care of this, see this issue for more details: https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/661

Answer (score 0):

1- make sure that you have updated all othe plugin you use to the latest version . For example using an old version of `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` can cause such problem

2- install   V6+ of  cordova ios

```
 ionic cordova platform rm ios 
 ionic cordova platform add ios@6.0.0
```

I strongly suggest that you perform   intensive smoke tests after upgrading .

Also I would consider migrating to Capacitor, although it does not fulfill all my needs ATM.